# Java - How can i make my application long run stable so that it does not hiccups, freeze?

Tags: java, linux, memory, jvm, ram

My Java skeleton is something like below.

Which works perfectly when i run it after system boot, for couple of hours. Since it run for 24 hours for 1 day long, i got issues with my application or JVM itself, such as hiccups/freeze issues, on press nothing happen its like `he is dead`.

It is happening for several times, my guess is memory issue when its running for long time, JVM somewhere is causing it, but not my application itself because first couple of hours it has zero downtime. Only get started for long run greater then 8 hours.

Example:

```
public class Boot {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
       String myCmd = "java -cp /var/tmp/dist/App.jar main.main";
       Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCmd);
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
          }
        });
  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        //Server port listener
      }
    }).start();

    .....

    window = new JWindow();

    window.add("North", panelBgImg);
    window.pack();
    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    window.setSize(screen.width, screen.height + 1);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    window.setVisible(true);        
  }
}
```

How can i make sure that JVM is not causing my application to be freeze, is there anyway to unit test this? Can this help to resolve this for long run?

e.g: System.gc () and Runtime.gc ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app freezes, the reason is more likely a deadlock of some sort than out of memory error. In the latter case, the JVM just dies with an exception. So my bet is that invoking the GC won't help you here.

Bugs like this are difficult to catch exactly because they are very hard to reproduce reliably. You have a couple of options though:

- insert debug log printouts into your code to get more clue about what's going on, then analyse the logs produced before / during your app got frozen
- stop the JVM (with the `kill` command or Ctrl+\ from console on Linux, Ctrl+Break on Windows) when your app is frozen - it will display thread dump info, listing all running and deadlocked threads
- run your app with VisualVM attached to see memory usage patterns

Answer (score 2):

Explicit calls to the garbage collector don't solve problems like this. In general you don't use them. The only possible exception is when you know you freed a lot of memory and you want to have it cleaned up before the next big task comes in (but even that doesn't really ever happen).

The best way to find what happens is to run visualvm (comes with the default jdk, in the bin/ dir). Connect to your application and start looking at its memory and cpu usage. If that makes you suspect memory is the problem, you can take snapshots and analyze them.